# How to Use Existing Stripe Flutter Packages

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement a Stripe payment system where users can pay me with their credits cards without opening a Stripe account. There are a few Stripe packages on Dart Packages website (https://pub.dartlang.org/). But unlike other third-party packages I used, these lack clear explanations in their example code.

[https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stripe_payment] stripe_payment's example code provides a credit card user-input template, but it's not clear how to charge their credit card after they enter the card info.

[https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stripe_api] stripe_api's example code provides some functions to create a customer session and add a card etc, but it's still not clear how to charge the user a USD amount and whether we are communicating with Stripe successfully.

[https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stripe] Dart stripe package -which is incompatible with Flutter due to mirror issues- does have examples in the test files but doesn't work with Flutter.

An example code that shows these steps would be really helpful:

> Set Test API Key -> Check connection with Stripe server -> Get User
>   Credit Card info -> Make a transaction with a given USD amount.

Comment: Does this https://gitlab.com/exitlive/stripe-dart/tree/master/test/api_resources not work in flutter? I think it does..